# How to export/import Netbeans templates

Tags: templates, netbeans, import, export

I am running Netbeans 7.0.1 under OS X and have created a number of templates using Tools > Templates. All my Templates are created under a new folder within the Templates folder list.

I would now like to export the Templates and share them with other members of my team.

How do I go about exporting them and then allowing my teammates to import them into their Netbean installs?

Note: I've located the templates under my ~/.netbeans directory, but was hoping the IDE would facilitate import/export so folks don't have to go around copying folders in the file system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just tested on my WinXP with Netbeans 7.0.1 and 7.1, so not 100% sure if it will work on OS X.

Open your Netbeans 7.0.1 and go to `Tools -> Options` and in the new windows left lower corner `Export`. In this window expand `Editor` by clicking `+`.

In the opened tree you only have to activate the checkbox in front of `Code Templates`, fill in a target file and there you are with your ready to import Templatesfile.

Your team members can import them by clicking `Import` in `Tools -> Options`.

Hope this will help you and your members.

[image]

Comment: They won't import back to a new installation. I've done this through the Years and I have to keep editing the entire thing :S

Answer (score 3):

Templates are saved in you `~/.netbeans/version/config/Templates/Properties`. You can import your template using :

```
Tools --> Templates --> Choose a directory then click "Add" button.
```

If you need more info maybe [this tuto](http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-i-setup-my-netbeans-templates.html) can help you.

Or in

```
Tools -->Options --> Editor pane --> Code templates pane
```

Choose your language, then at the bottom left you will found `Export` and `Import` button.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue when trying to store my preferences regarding "Code Templates" in my automatic backup. After I tried the `Tools >> Options >> Editor pane >> Code Templates pane` + `Export` trick suggested here, I found out by inspecting the exported archive file that the name of the settings' xml file I had to search for was `org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomCodeTemplates.xml` as stored in `AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Editors\text\x-java\CodeTemplates` (Windows) so I can use this path now directly in the auomated backup without exporting the file.